# Make PATH variable changes permanent on openSuse

Tags: shell, opensuse, environment-variables, path

Okay, so I'm trying to do something that should be rather simple but for some reason I can't quite seem to make it work.  All I simply want to do is add a path to the PATH environment variable in openSuse.

So far, I've edited the following line in /etc/default/su :

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin

with this line :

PATH=/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/php/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin

Basically, all I want to do is have access to php and mysqld regardless of how I log in directly from the command prompt without having to type trailing /usr/local/php/bin/ every time.  Am I even editing the right file?

I'm a bit of a Linux newbie and to achieve something as trivial as this is eluding me. Server gods out there, drop be a crumb, please? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `/etc/profile`, `/etc/csh.login`, `/etc/csh.cshrc`, indeed <strike>can</strike> (shan't) be changed.

However on Suse, if you notice that these files indicate that you *should use* any of these files `/etc/profile.local`, `/etc/csh.login.local` and `/etc/csh.chsrc.local` to establish local environmental modifications.  Making changes in these files should isolate you a little bit better in the event of upgrades to the basic packages which may modify these files.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, you should add it to the path.

Typically server-wide shell environment for bash is in `/etc/profile`.  For (t)csh it is `/etc/csh.login`.

Rather than setting the `PATH` system-wide, I'd recommend setting it for your individual user.  You would specify the `PATH` in `.bash_profile` or `.cshrc` in your home directory.

If you want recommendations for a different shell, you will need to identify what shell you use.  If your situation is a special case, you will need to provide additional details, such as how you are authenticating to what user.